# Rectilinear polygon

Tags: computational-geometry

It is possible to generate a random Rectilinear Polygon (without holes)
in WL? I found this option, but without any possibility to ask for a Rectilinear Polygon.

```
RandomPolygon["Convex", 2]
```

Comment: Conjection: Each convex rectilinear polygon is an axis-aligned rectangle. Or maybe you have special notion of convexity for rectilinear polygons? If so, please make it precise.

Comment: yes, you are right. When I say convex, I mean without holes.

Comment: Ah, you mean _connected_ and _simply connected_.

Comment: I'm not sure ...

Comment: In other words you ask for a set of numbers $x_i$ and $y_i$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n y_i=0$, right?

Comment: You might explore the [orthogonal convex hull](https://mathoverflow.net/q/219202/6094).

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke  you are right the orthogonal convex hull it is what I look for, but unfortunately, I do not succeed to implement it

Answer (score 2):

The number of vertices should be even and is given by `2 n` below

```
RRPoly[n_] := Module[{x, y, indx, indy},
  x = Accumulate[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n]];
  y = Accumulate[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n]];
  indx = Table[Quotient[i + 1, 2], {i, 2 n}];
  indy = RotateLeft[indx];
  Table[{x[[indx[[i]]]], y[[indy[[i]]]]}, {i, 2 n}]
  ]
```

Generate 3 random polygons with random colors.

```
Graphics[{Opacity[0.9], 
  Table[{RGBColor[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 3]], Polygon[RRPoly[5]]}, {k, 
    3}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[rectilinearPoly]
rectilinearPoly = Polygon@(Join @@ (Partition[#, 2, 1, 1] /.
    {{a_Real, b_}, {c_, d_}} :> {{a, b}, {c, b}, {c, d}})) &;
```

***Examples:***

```
SeedRandom[1]
coords =  RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {5, 6, 2}];

Row[Graphics[{EdgeForm[Gray], FaceForm[Opacity[.5, RandomColor[]]],  
    rectilinearPoly@#, Red, PointSize[Medium], Point@#}, ImageSize -> 1 -> 100]& /@
     (#[[FindShortestTour[#][[2]]]] & /@ coords), Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

```
Row[Graphics[{EdgeForm[Gray], FaceForm[Opacity[.5, RandomColor[]]], 
     rectilinearPoly@#, 
     Red, PointSize[Medium], Point@#}, ImageSize -> 1 -> 100] & /@ 
   coords, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]